# Speeding up WPF resizing/redrawing

Tags: c#, wpf, resize, redraw

Im noticing a black area displays when resizing even an empty WPF window. Alot of programs on my desktop dont have these issues.. So im wondering, is there a way to set a resize redraw priority or something, and speed up the resizing of WPF windows? or is this problem just unavoidable.

Comment: Are you using any custom window chrome?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382915/how-to-fix-the-wpf-form-resize-controls-lagging-behind-and-black-background

Comment: See my reply on this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382915/how-to-fix-the-wpf-form-resize-controls-lagging-behind-and-black-background/11004879#11004879 and two solutions, described here: http://wieser-software.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/wpf-window-rendering-woes.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is inherit to how WPF works and there is nothing you can do about this.

What you're seeing is the DirectX surface resizing and the entire surface redrawing, which takes a considerable amount of time.