# Black blank window while loading a window WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

In my application, on menu click we are launching a window. While loading, window will be black for few seconds and then controls will appears. I have attached the image here for reference. Please help me .[image] .

Comment: Your question is missing a description of desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Do you import and use WindowChrome class (System.Windows.Shell) in your project? when i import this class to my project this problem happened.

Comment: No. we are not using WindowChrome class in our project.but we are importing  [DllImport("user32.dll")]

Comment: set AllowsTransparency="True". this might fix your problem.

Comment: I tried using the above code, still not working as expected.

Comment: Can i use any other dll instead user32.dll to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should read this:

[How to fix the WPF form resize - controls lagging behind and black background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382915/how-to-fix-the-wpf-form-resize-controls-lagging-behind-and-black-background)

You can change the colour of the black bit that shows by calling the SetClassLong method as suggested by @@ghord:

```
public static class WindowExtensions
{
    private const int GCL_HBRBACKGROUND = -10;
    private const int COLOR_WINDOW = 5;

    public static void SetClassLong(this Window window)
    {
        //change the background colour of the window to "hide" possible black rendering artifacts
        IntPtr handle = new WindowInteropHelper(window).EnsureHandle();
        if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)
            SetClassLong(handle, GCL_HBRBACKGROUND, SafeNativeMethods.GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_WINDOW));
    }

    private static IntPtr SetClassLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, IntPtr dwNewLong)
    {
        if (IntPtr.Size > 4)
            return SafeNativeMethods.SetClassLongPtr64(hWnd, nIndex, dwNewLong);
        else
            return new IntPtr(SafeNativeMethods.SetClassLongPtr32(hWnd, nIndex, unchecked((uint)dwNewLong.ToInt32())));
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window, IViewFor<MainWindowViewModel>
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
        //change the background colour of the window to "hide" possible black rendering artifacts
        this.SetClassLong();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you suggest any other solution other than setting background brush.? Because i tried with all suggested solutions above but did't work for me...