# Trouble with "flickering" when updating a panel's children

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a `TableLayoutPanel` that contains rows of labels.  This control lives on form with a gradient background.  The labels are updated periodically, usually as a whole set.  When they are updated, they update very slowly and it is very visible to the user.

I have tried using `DoubleBuffered` on the form, but as expected, this didn't help.  Then I tried extending `TableLayoutPanel` and setting its `DoubleBuffered` property, but that seemed to make things worse.  I've also tried to `SuspendLayout()` on the table, but this didn't have any effect, either.

I've chosen this setup since the `DataGridView` doesn't support transparency...  I would really like to find an alternative to this setup, however.

[Other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333425/how-to-prevent-controls-visually-lagging-behind-on-resize-inside-tablelayoutpanel) seem related, but I haven't found one that solves the issue.

Any ideas on how to solve the update problem, or a possible alternative?

**EDIT** Since I'm dealing with a fixed number of datum to represent on this table, I'm looking into drawing the strings directly in the paint handler, rather than using the labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to eliminate the flicker was to use the paint handler of a custom control (such as a panel).  The other methods I tried seemed to reduce flicker, but nothing took it away.

Based on what I saw, the labels themselves are each doing something similar, and when their data is changed, they invalidate themselves.  There is no way to block this process, so the net effect is a scrolling/lagging update of each label to the next.  This is amplified on a complex background (such as an image).

By using the paint handler and calculating bounds for each "row," I was able to get the same table look for my application, and its background remains transparent.

It's not novel code, but here it is in case it helps someone else:

```
private const int RowCount = 10;
private DataTable _table;  // updated elsewhere

private void OnPaint(Object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
    if (! this.DesignMode) {
        DrawTable(e.Graphics);
    }
}

private void DrawTable(Graphics gfx) {
    SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor);
    for (int rownum = 0; rownum < RowCount; rownum++) {
        RectangleF rect = GetRowBounds(rownum);
        DrawRowNumber(gfx, rect, rownum);

        if (_table.Rows.Count > rownum) {
            DataRow data = _table.Rows[rownum];
            DrawName(gfx, rect, Convert.ToString(data["name"]));
            DrawCount(gfx, rect, Convert.ToSingle(data["count"]));
        }
    }
}

private void DrawRowNumber(Graphics gfx, RectangleF bounds, int place) {
    String str = String.Format("{0}.", (place + 1));
    SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor);
    gfx.DrawString(str, this.Font, brush, bounds.Location);
}

private void DrawName(Graphics gfx, RectangleF bounds, String name) {
    PointF loc = new PointF(80, bounds.Top);
    SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor);
    gfx.DrawString(name, this.Font, brush, loc);
}

private void DrawCount(Graphics gfx, RectangleF bounds, float score) {
    SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor);
    String str = score.ToString("N1");
    SizeF size = gfx.MeasureString(str, this.Font);
    float offset = bounds.Right - size.Width;
    PointF loc = new PointF(offset, bounds.Top);
    gfx.DrawString(str, this.Font, brush, loc);
}

private RectangleF GetRowBounds(int row) {
    if ((row < 0) || (row >= RowCount)) {
        return RectangleF.Empty;
    }

    Rectangle bounds = this.ClientRectangle;
    float height = (float) bounds.Height / (float) RowCount;

    PointF loc = new PointF(bounds.Left, height * row);
    SizeF size = new SizeF(bounds.Width, height);

    return new RectangleF(loc, size);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Are labels docked (meaning `label.Dock = DockStyle.Fill`)?

How many code there are between each `label.Text` change?

My application have exactly the same UI. Labels inside TableLayoutPanel inside TableLayoutPanel inside TableLayoutPanel. But without gradient background. Each panel and label has no margins and paddings. Each label is dock-filled. First we obtain all values for each label. And only after that we change all labels but in separate thread.

```
string[] texts = GetAllLabels();
ownerControl.Invoke(new Action(() =>
{
  for (int i = 0; i < UpdatingControls.Count && i < texts.Count; i++)
  {
    UpdatingControls[i].Text = texts[i];
  }
}));
```

This reduced (in our case) the blinking to the minimum.

Comment: The labels are docked and updated in a similar fashion to yours...  I may have to fall back on drawing the string directly in the paint handler.

Comment: Thanks for the help...  The only way I could eliminate the flicker was to use a custom paint handler.